# Meaning of time evolution of Floquet matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, greens-functions, time-evolution, floquet-theory

Consider the time-periodical Hamiltonian $H(t)=H(t+T)$. In the Floquet theorem, the Schrödinger equation has a solution of the form
\begin{align}
|\psi_\alpha(t)\rangle=e^{-i\epsilon_\alpha t}|\phi_\alpha(t)\rangle,
\end{align}
where $|\phi_\alpha(t)\rangle=|\phi_\alpha(t+T)\rangle$. This Floquet eigenstates satisfy
\begin{align}
\left(H(t)-i  \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\left|\phi_{\alpha}(t)\right\rangle=\epsilon_{\alpha}\left|\phi_{\alpha}(t)\right\rangle.
\end{align}
After the Fourier transformation, we get time-independent equation
\begin{align}
H_F|\Phi\rangle\rangle=\epsilon_\alpha |\Phi\rangle\rangle,
\end{align}
where the state $|\Phi\rangle\rangle$ belongs to the extended Hilbert space $\mathcal{L}^2(0,T)\otimes \mathcal{H}$ whose ONB is written as $\{|n\rangle\otimes|a\rangle\}_{n,a}$.

---

My question is as follows: I think the eigenstates and eigenvalue of $H_F$ are important because we can extract the information of the dynamics. However, is there any meaning of $\exp(-iH_Ft)$? I cannot understand the meaning because the dynamics which is described by
\begin{align}
i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi(t)\rangle\rangle=H_F|\Psi(t)\rangle\rangle
\end{align}
does not include any information of $|\psi_\alpha(t)\rangle$.

---

Sometimes people consider the Green's function of $H_F$. However, if there is not any meaning of $\exp(-iH_Ft)$, I do not understang the reason why people consider the Green's funtion of $H_F$.